# tippy plugin cannot show multiple tooltips with HTML content

Tags: jquery, tippyjs

I have a tippy plugin initialized this way:

```
tippy('.tooltip_commands', {
                    delay: 100,
                    arrow: true,
                    arrowType: 'round',
                    size: 'large',
                    duration: 500,
                    animation: 'scale',
                    placement: 'left',
                    interactive: true,
                    trigger: 'click',
                    content: document.querySelector('#tooltip_content').cloneNode(true)
                });
```

Where "tooltip_content" is:

```
<div class="tooltip_templates">
    <div id="tooltip_content">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a id="_bajarFactura" href="#" title="Bajar factura"><i class="sl-icon-cloud-download"></i>Bajar factura original</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a id="_verFactura" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" title="Ver archivo de la factura"><i class="sl-icon-doc"></i>Ver factura original</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a id="_verDetalle" href="#" title="Ver detalles de la factura"><i class="sl-icon-magnifier-add"></i>Ver Detalle</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a id="_reEnviar" href="#" title="Re-enviar factura a un e-mail"><i class="icon-Mail-Forward"></i>Re-enviar</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And "tooltip_commands" are several buttons in a TABLE (one button for each row).

After I run the page, only the last row shows the tooltip with the HTML content. All other rows shows the tooltip, but empty.

Is there a way to solve it?

Please see this Fiddle with the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/desytec/ym4nubhw/21/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the tippy function, JavaScript first evaluates your arguments. Most importantly the *content* property of the *options* object will get evaluated:

```
document.querySelector('#tooltip_content').cloneNode(true)
```

This expression will evaluate to a **single copy** of the *#tooltip_content* element. Tippy then will try to assign this same single copy of your tooltip to every popup.

In order for your example to work correctly **you have to create a tooltip container element for each tooltip you create**. I would do this with a [jQuery loop](https://api.jquery.com/each/), but there are many other solutions as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.tooltip_commands').each(function(){
                tippy(this, {
                    delay: 100,
                    arrow: true,
                    arrowType: 'round',
                    size: 'large',
                    duration: 500,
                    animation: 'scale',
                    placement: 'left',
                    interactive: true,
                    trigger: 'click',
                    theme: 'honeybee',
                    content: document.querySelector('#tooltip_content').cloneNode(true)
                });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ``document.querySelector('#tooltip_content').cloneNode(true)
`` was realy helpful.